# Relacion anidada no filtra con where en laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, composer, relaciones

Necesito filtrar una consulta de productos de determinada empresa mediante el area de productos. pero  es como que ignorara el where. la información es la siguiente :

1. La tabla **producto_empresa** se relaciona con |**productos** |**empresas|valores_productos**| y la tabla **producto** se relaciona con **areas_productos**.
2. Cada modelo tiene las relaciones correspondientes... por lo tanto el modelo **ProductoEmpresa** tiene relacion con todo menos con **AreaProducto**

Tengo esto con id 5 para controlar los datos :

```
 $productosEmpresa=ProductoEmpresa::with(['empresa','producto.areaProducto'=>
                                                                          function ($query) {
                                                                          $query->where('areas_productos.id','5');},
                                                                        'valorProducto'])->paginate(10);
```

y con eso me muestra todos los registros sin filtrar por id=5 la salida es normal y con los datos de todas las tablas que necesito, solo que no filtra.

```
//modelo: ProductoEmpresa
 function producto()
 {
    return $this-> belongsTo(Producto::class);
 }
 function empresa()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(Empresa::class);
 }
 function valorProducto()
 {
   $todos_los_valores= $this->hasMany(ValorProducto::class);
   return $todos_los_valores->where('estado',1);
 }

//Modelo:Producto
public function areaProducto(){
  return $this->belongsTo(AreaProducto::class);
}
public function productoempresa(){
  return $this->hasMany(productoEmpresa::class);
}  

//Modelo:AreaProducto
public function productos()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Producto::class);
}
```

Comment: Deberias quitar el `where('areas_productos.id','5')` y poner `where('id','5')`, porque estas usando el `with`, por lo cual no es necesario referenciar la tabla

Comment: Tampoco funcionó :/  me arroja  los que tienen id: 5,4,3,2,1 , es decir, toda la Base de datos.